# Remove table border

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to remove the following border but I do not know how to do it.

[image]

How would I be able accomplish to remove this using CSS? Please help me out, it's very much appriciated!

---

My HTML and CSS below:

```css
table {
    width:100%;
 font-size:14px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #00b0f0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 176, 240, 0.1);
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table th {
    background-color:#00b0f0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>::1</td>
    <td>8-5-2016
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="index.php?page=bruteforce&action=verwijderitem&id=1">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/2.gif" class="iconbtn" alt="Verwijder" title="Verwijder" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the border from the left side of the last `div` and right side of the previous `div`.

So I have added two classes `.no-left-border` and `.no-right-border` and applied them to the applicable `td` tags.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #00b0f0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 176, 240, 0.1);
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
table th {
  background-color: #00b0f0;
  color: white;
}
.no-border-right {
  border-right: none;
}
.no-border-left {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>::1</td>
    <td class="no-border-right">8-5-2016</td>
    <td class="no-border-left">
      <a href="index.php?page=bruteforce&action=verwijderitem&id=1">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/2.gif" class="iconbtn" alt="Verwijder" title="Verwijder" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **left border** from the **last** TD  `:nth-last-child(1){`
Remove the **right border** from the **penultimate** TD `:nth-last-child(2){`

```css
table {
    width:100%;
 font-size:14px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #00b0f0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 176, 240, 0.1);
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table th {
    background-color:#00b0f0;
    color: white;
}
table tr td:nth-last-child(1){   /* LAST TD */
   border-left: none;
}
table tr td:nth-last-child(2){   /* PENULTIMATE TD */
   border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>::1</td>
    <td>8-5-2016
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="index.php?page=bruteforce&action=verwijderitem&id=1">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/2.gif" class="iconbtn" alt="Verwijder" title="Verwijder" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Due to border collapse, even if you see 1px border there's actually two overlapping borders, so you have to remove both borders accordingly to achieve the needed result (no border).

Answer (score 0):

## Working code & preview

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body,th,td
            {
                font-family:Arial,Helvitica,Sans;
                font-size:13px;
            }
        
            table
            { border-spacing:0; }

            th
            {
                background:#00b0f0;
                color:#FFF;
                border: 1px solid #00b0f0;
                padding:0.4em;
                text-align:left;
            }

            td
            {
                min-width:70px;
                background:#e6f7fe;
                border: 1px solid #00b0f0;
                padding:0.8em;
            }

            .blank
            {
                background:none;
                border:none;
            }

            .no-line-l
            { border-left:none; }

            .no-line-r
            { border-right:none; }

            .the-x
            {
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:right;
                color:#A00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th class="blank"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="no-line-r">::1</td>
                <td class="no-line-r">8-5-2016</td>       
                <td class="no-line-l the-x">X</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Preview

[image]